# Allowing external users to access sharepoint folders

Tags: sharepoint, power-automate

This should be so easy, I feel embarrassed for asking, but I just cannot find this info anywhere, or I'm doing something wrong.

I'm creating sharelinks for folders using Power Automate. You can only create 'anyone' links, or anyone in the organisation, but I'm specifically sending these links to clients, so I'm creating anyone links.

But hey are receiving 'Sorry, something went wrong' errors when they click on the link.

I've set all the settings correctly as far as I can tell. I've gone to Sharepoint Admin settings and increased the level to the max allowance, and I've gone to the individual site settings and allowed sharing with anyone.

Am I missing a setting somewhere? Sharepoint is really frustrating for a) requiring you to go to 6 different places to switch a feature on and b) changin it's interface every 6 weeks, so any tutorial or instructions online are instantly out of date.

Chat GPT is, of course, useless, talking about menu items that don't exist.So any help from a human who has done this before would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ignore me. Turns out I had done everything right. Left it for a couple of hours, and then the same link from the same email worked. Tested on incognito and different accounts, definitely works now. I love computers sometimes!